# $A,B$ are $n×n$ matrices such that $A^2B^2=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices of order $n×n$ such that $A^2B^2=0$ then show that $B^2A^2=0$.

Pre- and post-multiplying the given equation $A^2B^2=0$ by $B^2$ and $A^2$ respectively, I get $(B^2A^2)^2=0$, so at least we have that $B^2A^2$ is nilpotent of degree at most $2$. But I don't see how to proceed from here.

Comment: Please show some effort: What have you tried? MSE is not a place where monkeys make your homework for you.

Comment: What I have tried is as follows::A^2B^2=0.then pre and post multiply by B^2 and A^2 respectively. Thus I get (B^2A^2)^2=0 implies nilpotent.but couldn't prove the required thing.

Comment: The statement isn’t true (with $n=4$ at least); could you check if you have any more assumptions?

Comment: I also think some more assumptions are needed!!

Answer (score 6):

A counterexample with $n=2$:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad
B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

These are both idempotent i.e. $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B.$ We have
$$AB=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad
BA=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$